# Remove element from XML with ElementTree

Tags: xml, python-2.7, xml-parsing, elementtree

I have the following code which prints out the name of the element I want to remove:

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

tree = ET.parse('myfile.xml')
root = tree.getroot()

for elem in tree.iter(tag='test'):
    print elem.tag
```

How do I remove this element from my XML? My XML is similar to the following:

```
<foo>
   <bar>
      <level>
         <test name="1">
            <stuff>
               hello
            </stuff>
         </test>
         <test name="2">
            <stuff>
               hello
            </stuff>
         </test>
      </level>   
   </bar>
</foo>
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Based on the information provided, you need to have pointer to parent tag in order to remove child tag. I have updated your code accordingly.

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

tree = ET.parse('myfile.xml')
root = tree.getroot()

for test in root.iter('test'):
    for stuff in test.findall('stuff'):
       test.remove(stuff)

print ET.tostring(root)
```

Output:

```
<foo>
   <bar>
      <level>
         <test name="1">
            </test>
         <test name="2">
            </test>
      </level>
   </bar>
</foo>
```

I hope this helps!